# Manipular serviços com powershell

Tags: services, powershell

Criei um script para iniciar e parar um serviço. Minha intenção é poder iniciar ou parar um serviço através de um simples click de mouse em um atalho no desktop.
Criei um atalho para o script e no campo destino nas propriedades do atalho adicionei os argumentos `PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File`. O atalho está funcionando mas para que ele consiga manipular os serviços tenho que executá-lo como administrador o que tem me obrigado a clicar com o botão direito sobre o atalho e escolher executar como administrador.
Minha intenção é fazer com que o modo administrador seja o padrão do atalho para que eu possa executá-lo com dois cliques.
Aproveitando a pergunta, gostaria de saber o que significa os argumentos `-ExecutionPolicy ByPass` pois essa dica foi me dada em outro fórum e eu já pesquisei e não encontrei o significado desses argumento no atalho.
Abaixo segue o script:

```
if((Get-Service -Name 'MSSQL$SQLEXDEV').Status -eq "Running")
{
    Stop-Service -Name 'MSSQL$SQLEXDEV'
    Set-Service -Name 'MSSQL$SQLEXDEV' -StartupType Disabled
}
else
{
    Set-Service -Name 'MSSQL$SQLEXDEV' -StartupType Manual
    Restart-Service -Name 'MSSQL$SQLEXDEV'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma mais simples para executar o script como Administrador por padrão, é configurar diretamente o atalho para "Executar como administrador":

- Clique com o botão direto do mouse no atalho e selecione
  "Propriedades"
- Na guia "Atalho", clique no botão "Avançados"
- Selecione a opção "Executar como administrador" e depois clique em
  "Ok" e "Ok" novamente

Caso você prefira alterar o privilégio de execução diretamente no código do script, você pode fazê-lo conforme descrito abaixo:

```
# Obtém o ID do usuário
$myWindowsID=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()

# Obtém informações do grupo ao qual o usuário pertence
$myWindowsPrincipal=new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($myWindowsID)
 
# Obtém informações sobre o grupo "Administrador"
$adminRole=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator
 
# Verifica se a execução atual já está em modo elevado
# Essa verificação é necessária para que o script não entre em looping
if (-Not ($myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole)))
{ 
   # Cria um novo processo do PowerShell
   $newProcess = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "PowerShell";
   
   # Informa como parâmetro para o novo processo, o caminho do script atual
   $newProcess.Arguments = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition;
   
   # Parâmetro para o novo processo que solicita a
   # execução em modo elevado (Administrador)
   $newProcess.Verb = "runas";
   
   # Inicia o novo processo
   [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($newProcess);
   
   # Encerra o processo atual (que está em modo Usuário)
   exit
}

# Aqui, você coloca o código que será executado pelo seu script em modo Administrador
if((Get-Service -Name 'MSSQL$SQLEXDEV').Status -eq "Running")
{
    Stop-Service -Name 'MSSQL$SQLEXDEV'
    Set-Service -Name 'MSSQL$SQLEXDEV' -StartupType Disabled
}
else
{
    Set-Service -Name 'MSSQL$SQLEXDEV' -StartupType Manual
    Restart-Service -Name 'MSSQL$SQLEXDEV'
}
```

Fonte: [A self elevating PowerShell script - por Benjamin Armstrong](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/virtual_pc_guy/a-self-elevating-powershell-script)

Conforme a documentação do parâmetro [-ExecutionPolicy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.1):

Este parâmetro determina a política de execução do PowerShell para a máquina, para um usuário, ou para uma sessão.

As regras definidas para a política de execução do PowerShell tem por objetivo auxiliar o usuário a não executar scripts por "engano" ou "descuido".

Essas regras não são políticas de segurança e não impedem que o usuário execute um determinado código de forma diferente das regras definidas no ExecutionPolicy.

De forma simples, existem seis políticas principais:

- **Restricted** - não permite a execução de scripts
- **AllSigned** - permite somente a execução de scripts assinados digitalmente
- **RemoteSigned** - permite a execução de scripts desenvolvidos localmente sem assinatura. Caso o script tenha sido obtido através de download (remoto), deve ter assinatura digital
- **Unrestricted** - permite a execução de scripts sem assinatura, mas avisa o usuário caso o script tenha sido obtido através de download
- **Bypass** - executa qualquer script sem aviso nenhum
- **Undefined** - política indefinida. O PowerShell busca por uma política padrão do usuário ou da máquina. Caso todas sejam indefinidas, o padrão é "Restricted"

Recomendo consultar a documentação desse parâmetro para maiores detalhes, pois existem várias estratégias de configurações possíveis.